# HTML5 API Geolocation broken on Firefox (recent)

Tags: html, api, geolocation

I'm posting this message because I haven't seen any recent question on the subject. I have a web app using HTML5 geolocation, and it worked just fine on Firefox. Until yesterday, it suddenly stopped working. I don't remember seeing any update yesterday, so I'm a bit surprised.

When I go [here](http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp), it doesn't work since yesterday.

My question is : what makes this geolocation API so unreliable, and is there any good alternative to it?

Thank you

EDIT : Seems to work again now, but it's weird, and makes me curious about what can cause that.

Answer (score 0):

When I go to the w3schools link you provided the geolocation works just fine in Firefox (and Chrome).

Are you sure didn't accidentally Deny the permission to access your location?

Comment: I tested again and now it seems to work. It's weird, I tried on 2 different computers and asked a friend to try it as well, it didn't work yesterday night and this morning, I'm sure ^^. I'm really curious to know what could have caused that.

Comment: Broken again just now, it's really weird and unconsistent

Comment: Well it is still working for me but I have noticed that while Chrome does it instantly Firefox takes 5-10 seconds to get it. See if yours isn't working at all or if it is just taking a long time.

Also you could modify your code as they have it here:
http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_geolocation_error
To show the error messages associated with the failure. Perhaps it will give more insight into what is going wrong.

Comment: Yes thank you (I have the message "Location information is unavailable"). I'll just add the errors to my webapp, I can't do much more anyway.